# Symfony & js : button not working in certain conditions

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig, shopware, shopware6

I have a simple "plus/minus" functionality for the product quantity on the product detail page on a shopware6 site (version 6.4.8.1) (See attached image) [image]

See here my code in /views/storefront/page/product-detail/buy-widget-form.html.twig.

```
{% block page_product_detail_buy_quantity_container %}
<div class="col-12 quantity-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5 col-md-3 label-quantity">
            <span>{{ "detail.labelQuantity"|trans|sw_sanitize }}</span>
        </div>
         <div class="col-7 col-md-9 quantity-input-panel">
                    {% block page_product_detail_buy_quantity %}
                            <div class="quantity-inner">
                                    <span class="min button" id="moins" {#onclick="minus()"#}> {% sw_icon 'minus' %} </span>
                                    <input id="amountToBasket" type="text" name="lineItems[{{ page.product.id }}][quantity]" value="{{product.minPurchase}}" autocomplete="off" maxlength="2" class="form-control">
                                    <input id="minPurchase" type="hidden" name="minPurchase" value="{{product.minPurchase}}" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
                                    <input id="maxRange" type="hidden" name="maxRange" value="{{product.calculatedMaxPurchase}}" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
                                    <input id="purchaseSteps" type="hidden" name="purchaseSteps" value="{{product.purchaseSteps}}" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
                                    <span class="plus button" id="plus" {#onclick="plus()"#}> {% sw_icon 'plus' %}</span>
                            </div>
                    {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And here's my js file related to the plus/minus buttons.

```
var minPurchase = $("#minPurchase").val();
var maxRange = $("#maxRange").val();
var count = $("#amountToBasket").val();

$("#plus").click(function () {
    if (count < maxRange){
        count++;

        $("#amountToBasket").val(count);
    }
});

$("#moins").click(function () {
    if (count > minPurchase){
        count--;

        $("#amountToBasket").val(count);
    }
});
```

**PROBLEM** : This works perfectly for ALL products where the minimum purchase quantity is ***equal** to 1*. BUT if we click on the plus or the minus for every product having the minimum purchase quantity ***greater** than 1*, it's doing nothing. It gives the impression that the buttons are deactivated in this case.

Do you have any clue on what is going on?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/qbx3dgoz/) make sure your attribute `calculatedMaxPurchase` actually returns a valid value or you need to modify your javascript to alter for products which have no max "range"

Comment: Yeah, that's a good guess but the max order quantity is set to 150 for all products (I checked the one I am testing with to make sure).

Comment: Check the demo I've posted. The only things I've changed is replacing your variables with real numbers and everything works. Rather than posting the template, I'd suggest you to post the generated output

Comment: If that would be the real issue, It would not work with all products, right? Cause here it works https://bakery.vanparys.com/detail/665b54d672e14ab781cf214f08a5c065, and here it does not https://bakery.vanparys.com/detail/690d3e59e2e144f8a3d8b7fea3f7e07f

Comment: I did an "echo" of the {{product.calculatedMaxPurchase}} and it's outputting 150 as it should.

Comment: No clue, but I mean the `minPurchase` shoudln't affect the `plus` button. Anyway got it working with your live code by parsing the value  to int's rather than using `.val()` directly. So change your code to `var count = parseInt($("#amountToBasket").val());`, etc.

Comment: It worked indeed ! Big Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as replied by @DarkBee, I simply needed to specify the value type of the "count" function.

```
var count = parseInt($("#amountToBasket").val());
```